# Subviews of UIView misplaced when the parent view is in StackView

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a button with a gradient border, everything works fine until I nest the `GradientButton` in a `StackView`. Then, I get this result for the last button in the horizontal `StackView`. Why is the subview becomes misplaced always for the last item?

[image]

**Here is the GradientButton I created:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class GradientButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var startColor:  UIColor = UIColor.momaBackgroundGradient.begin
    @IBInspectable var endColor:    UIColor = UIColor.momaBackgroundGradient.end
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 2
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 4

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let gradientBorder = UIView(frame: self.frame)
        gradientBorder.configureGradient(withColors: [self.startColor, self.endColor], isHorizontal: true)
        gradientBorder.mask(withPath: UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.frame.insetBy(dx: self.borderWidth, dy: self.borderWidth), cornerRadius: self.frame.height/2), inverse: true)
        gradientBorder.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height/2
        gradientBorder.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.addSubview(gradientBorder)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show an image of the unexpected results you are getting? Where is your nesting code?

Comment: There is an image on top... you see the weird orange thing on the right, this is  the second button inner view that appear way off

Comment: Have you checked the constraints for your stackView??

Comment: Do you have it on github?? I could try and contribute

Comment: Change `let gradientBorder = UIView(frame: self.frame)` to `let gradientBorder = UIView(frame: self.bounds)`

Comment: There is not enough context in this question to help. Consider adding how you configure your stack view and how that stack view is configured in its superview preferably in a project that illustrates it :)

Comment: @Mihai thanks you found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gradient view is using it's parent's `frame` on init. Change it to `bounds` like so:

```
let gradientBorder = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
```

Comment: Though im not entirely sure why bounds isnt acting the same as frame

Comment: Because the frame is the position of a view in it's parent view. Bounds are basically expressed in it's own coordinate system.

Comment: See this for more details (i think this is for Cocoa where the coordinate system is in a different direction but the idea is the same) https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html

Answer (score 0):

```
/Text Label
let textLabel = UILabel()
textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
textLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.width).isActive = true
textLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true
textLabel.text  = "Hi World"
textLabel.textAlignment = .center

//Stack View
let stackView   = UIStackView()
stackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
stackView.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.equalSpacing
stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
stackView.spacing   = 16.0

stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel)
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

self.view.addSubview(stackView)

//Constraints
stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

for storyboard

[image]

Comment: My stackview is in a storyboard... I don't understand how that fixes my issue

Comment: add fixed width for all 3 elements in the parent stackview and add an another element(view,label,stack etc..) into the parent stackView without fixed width

pls let me kow if any doubts,else give upvote

Comment: I'm not sure how this will fix my issue, it seems like a weird workaround... I have 2 UIButton in a stackview, you're talking about 3 view in the stackview and a fourth one without width constraint? Wait whut? :\

Comment: so add 2 uibuttons with fixed width and add an empty stack without width(rightmost)

Comment: can you share github link?